# Why is there no refraction of light when it passes through a semi circular surface but refraction takes place at the surface of a convex lens

Tags: waves, lenses

A convex lens has a curved surface just like that of a semi circular block. When light passes through the curved surfce of the semicircular block it doesnt refract. But when light does it refracts alough it passes through the curved surface.

Answer (score 4):

In general, light *does* refract when it passes through the curved face of a semicircular glass block. But when you use such a block in school experiments you usually direct the beam of light at the circle centre, that is the centre of the flat face. Therefore light enters (or leaves) the curved face along a circle radius. But the radii are normals to the curved face, and there is no refraction when light enters or leaves a different medium along a normal to the interface. But if you send the light into or out of the curved face of the block along some other line than a radius, there is refraction!